# Selecting everything apart from where column meets certain criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I am fairly new to SQL and having a problem with the following code:

```
SELECT
in_profiles.profiles AS IncludeProfiles
,no_profiles.profiles AS ExcludeProfiles
, data.*,

CASE
    WHEN data.travel_type NOT LIKE 'car' THEN data.reason_code <> 'PT' ELSE
END CASE

FROM transportation_data data
```

Comment: Can you add some sample table data and the expected result. (All as formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Please provide a better explanation of what you are trying to do.  Your title needs to be expounded upon.

Comment: Are in_profiles.profiles and no_profiles.profiles in a table other than transportation_data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You decide what you want to return using a where clause. In this case it doesn't seem to matter what reason_code is for car so given

```
drop table if exists transportation_data;
create table transportation_data (travel_type varchar(10), reason_code varchar(3));
insert into transportation_data values
('car','pt'),('car','xx'),
('bus','pt'),('bus','xx');
```

The query could look like this

```
SELECT data.*
FROM transportation_data data
where travel_type = 'car' or (travel_type <> 'car' and reason_code <>'pt')
```

Result

```
+-------------+-------------+
| travel_type | reason_code |
+-------------+-------------+
| car         | pt          |
| car         | xx          |
| bus         | xx          |
+-------------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Or possibly this

```
SELECT data.*
FROM transportation_data data
where reason_code <> 'pt' or travel_type = 'car' 

+-------------+-------------+
| travel_type | reason_code |
+-------------+-------------+
| car         | pt          |
| car         | xx          |
| bus         | xx          |
+-------------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Depending on taste